# Adding a char to a variable name

Tags: c++, variables, char

In my case, the code I want looks something like this:

```
anRow0[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
anRow1[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
anRow2[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
int place(int nVar1, int nVar2) //Where nVar1 is the row and nVar2 = current turn
{
    int nVert = 0;
    while (anRow\i want to add nVar1 here\[nVert+1] && nVert < 6)
    {
        nVert += 1;
    }
    anRow[nVert] = nVar2;
    return true;
}
```

I could make several "`if (nVar1 == 0) //check` for anRow1[] etc. but that seems inefficient.
Is there a way to add a number like this? Also, please ignore the rest of code, I know you could for example replace the while with a for, but that's besides the point.

Appreciate any help

Comment: Why not just using 2d array? p.s. c++ does not support much metaprogramming

Comment: `anRow\i want to add nVar1 here\[nVert+1]` ?

Comment: How do you format a 2d array in c++? I I've seen array[x,y] but that doesnt seem to work. the anRow\i want to add nVar here\means i just want to "paste" the characters of nVar to the name of anRow. But a 2d array is better, just that Im not sure how to write one.

Comment: @user2798044 When you saw `array[x,y]` you were looking at a different language, in C++ it's `array[x][y]`

Comment: @user2798044 I'm wondering why you asked about adding chars to a variable name when you knew that a 2D array is better. Why not just ask about a 2D array? This is a classic case of the XY problem, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: That was the kind of ideas I had in my early lines... Your answer, as everybody is telling you, is in the matrices or n-dimensional arrays. Good luck!

Comment: Great, thanks, should be easy from now on

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you want a *two dimensional* array, something like this

```
int an[3][6] = {{0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, {0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, {0,0,0,0,0,0,0}};

int place(int nVar1, int nVar2)
{
    int nVert = 0;
    while (nVert < 6 && an[nVar1][nVert+1])
    {
        nVert += 1;
    }
    an[nVar1][nVert] = nVar2;
    return true;
}
```

Although that code is undoubtedly bugged (would be better with `nVert < 5`). Still fixing the bugs is another question.

Answer (score 1):

You could put the arrays in another array, like this:

```
std::vector<int*> allRows = {
    anRow0,
    anRow1,
    anRow2
};
```

Then use a variable to index the `allRows` vector, like

```
allRows[i][nVert] = nVar2;
```

---

Or better, use an `std::array` of `std::array`:

```
std::array<std::array<int, 7>, 3> allRows = {{
    {{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }},
    {{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }},
    {{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }}
}};
```

Comment: Isn't mixing containters and arrays like this a bad practice? Of course it solves the problem at hand, but still...

Answer (score 1):

You could use a two dimensional array instead of 3 1-dimensional arrays.
You can read something about them here: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/

Here's a possible modification:

```
int an[3][7] = {0};
int place(int nVar1, int nVar2) //Where nVar1 is the row and nVar2 = current turn
{
    int nVert = 0;
    while (anRow[nVar2][nVert+1] && nVert < 6)
    {
        nVert += 1;
    }
    anRow[nVert] = nVar2;
    return true;
}
```

By the way, why are you are returning "true" although the return value is an int. It's allowed, but I would recommend not doing it. Return 1 instead, or change the return value to boolean.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, since C is a compiled language and the variable names are translated to memory addresses. At run-time, the code does not even know the name of the variables in your source code.

If you want to choose a value by runtime-data, you will always have to use arrays. There are multiple options here, the best for C++ is to use some of the STL-containers (std::array, std::vector, std::list, ...), but you may also use C-style arrays.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot manipulate the names of variables, functions, or really anthing syntactically - if you really need this C++ is the wrong language. There may be some very limited set of functionality available by using preprocessor macros, but that is *really* not what you want.

Instead use containers to store your variables:

```
std::vector<std::array<int, 7>> rows;
```